# GET request from Arduino to PHP (with several variables)

Tags: php, c++, mysql, get, arduino

I'm trying to use GET request to upload some values from Arduino to my web server. The problem with this part of code is that only "teller1" is requested but not "teller2". So "teller2" is not updated in MySQL server.

Hope someone can help me figure out the problem here :)

```
    if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");

    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");
  int value1 = 40;
  int value2 = 40;

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.print("GET /arduino.php?teller1=");
    client.print(value1);
    client.print("&teller2=");
    client.print(value2);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.0");
    client.println("Host: 158.36.70.50");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried logging out `"GET /arduino.php?teller1="value1"&teller2="value2` to see what the value is?

Comment: @TomHart Syntax error, and when I try to add + in between, I get another error saying: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char [10]’ to binary ‘operator+’